# Property values replacement in configuration file before MSI is being packaged

Tags: visual-studio-2010, environment-variables, app-config, distribution

I have a `Windows.Forms` client that is packaged as `MSI` by using a `Visual Studio Deployment Project`.

My `app.config` has some configuration properties whose values must be replaced by the correct ones depending on the environment I want to deploy the client into.

For instance, my client do connect to a set of COM+ services that are behind a WCF facade, so I have some `URL`s in the configuration file that vary depending on the environment (development, integration, etc etc).

In such way one can find in the application config line like this:

```
<add ServiceName="MyService" ServiceEndpoint="$(WS_URL)/MyService.svc" MaxMessageSize="xxxxxx"></add>
```

Well, the thing is that I need to execute a batch file (`.bat`) to load some variables and then replace the variables in the `app.config`, but, I need to do the replacements in the application configuration file that is being packaged in the `MSI`, and not perform the replacement in the "original" configuration file that is in the client project.

In fact what **I would need is just to get the path, of the application configuration file, that VS is about to package**, and pass the file-path to my script so that it does the replacements.

**NOTE:** In the above sample line **$(WS_URL)** is the variable that must be replaced by its correct value depending on the deployment environment configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have the solution that fit our needs. My need was mainly to just have one unique configuration file for the Windows.Forms client and being able to replace some property values in it, just before the file is packaged in the MSI.

I thought the binaries that are packaged within the MSI were taken from the project(s) output dir., but they are not, so I couldn't use that location to execute our "variable replacer" script and get the final `App.config` file ready to be  packaged.

We a have a `.bat` file, one for each kind of environment configuration, in which we centralize the configuration properties applying for Windows.Forms, Web-Applications, COM+ Serviced Components, so I was disgusted with the idea of replicating the configuration file of the client, because my aim is also to reduce the number of configuration files, to reduce the risk of making a mistake, while keeping the process of creating/maintaining build environments easy.

I couldn't find any doc to tell me how could I get the path, of the temporal folder or whatever, where the files are, just before the MSI is being packaged. If I would have access to it, then I would have executed our "variable replacer" script pointing to that directory and problem solved.

My workaround was to place a customized pre-build event, so that the I copy the "template" `App.config` to the project directory, and once it is there, I run the script to replace the property values.

Now, every time the deployment project is built, we are sure it contains a valid configuration file.

Just FYI, here is how the pre-build event looks like:

```
XCOPY /Y $(ProjectDir)config\*.* $(ProjectDir)
CALL ..\ScriptsCentral\do_apply_config.bat $(ProjectDir)App.config etc
EXIT 0
```

NOTE: I had to put the `EXIT 0` explicitly because we build all the projects with `msbuild` and `devenv.com` and I got the build process stopped in the part where it executes the build event.

(thanks @ChristopherPainter for your time and comments. +1 for your proposal)

Answer (score 1):

I would create 2 copies of your App.Config in source control and associate one with your project for F5 builds / dev debugging and another one that gets consumed by the installer for production use.

Comment: Thanks. But, well, I have many applications, this only one of them. The rest of the "system" is composed of COM+ Services and many web-applications, scheduled tasks and clients, and a bunch of configuration files. Normally, a new deployment of the our server components implies new deployments of clients, because one of the DOM classes has been changed or the signature of some methods has changed, etc. So, I would like to keep the variables dependent on the environment as much centralized as possible, and do not replicate the configuration files but rather transform them.

Comment: I think I'm arriving to a method that at least will go in such direction of keep as less as configuration files as possible and do transform them depending on the environment. I'll post it when I get the solution.

Comment: FWIW, this isn't an install problem. This is a source control, build problem.

Comment: I didn't mean was an install problem.

Comment: I'll remove the installer related tags then.

Comment: BTW, using tools like InstallShield and Windows Installer XML  it's possible to do the transformation (using xpath statements) at install time.  But I reserve this for data not known until install time.   For data known at build time, it's better to handle upstream and keep the installer simpler.

Comment: I want to let developers and people involved in the deployment forget about configuration files because configuration files are the one of the most critical parts of the deployment (at least in our project) and one error in the configuration file may lead to catastrophic consecuences. So once I have one build-server prepared for the pre-production environment I want the guy that is preparing the branch of code, managing the Visual Studio to compile and prepare the distro, as much possible, to forget that configuration files exist.